# Birthday dropdown list

Tags: php, registration

I want user to enter his birthday from dropdown menu during registration.I searched for code and got this

```
    <tr>
      <td><label>Birthday:</label></td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-container">
        <select name="month"><option value="0">Month:</option><?=generate_options(1,12,'callback_month')?></select>
        <select name="day"><option value="0">Day:</option><?=generate_options(1,31)?></select>
        <select name="year"><option value="0">Year:</option><?=generate_options(date('Y'),1900)?></select>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

But this code is not working.Please show some error or provide with better dropdown menu code.

Comment: better to use Jquery datepicker for date selection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that short_open_tag is disabled on your PHP setup.
instead of

```
 <?= generate_options(
```

you might need to code as

```
<?php
 echo generate_options(
```

then next step, We still need to know what error your page is showing.
try this code on a new file called **index2.php**

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    define('INCLUDE_CHECK',1);
    require "functions.php";
?>
<html>
<body>
    <?=generate_options(1,12,'callback_month')?>
```

---

below this are previous answers...

What error did you get?
if its undefined function **generate_options** , then you'll need to add that function in your page.

Can you supply more detail so we can answer this?
Can you also mention the page you took it from?

if you got it from here
http://tutorialzine.com/2009/08/creating-a-facebook-like-registration-form-with-jquery/
You'll need to copy the PHP code from that page as well.

---

You'll need to add the php code either on top or at the bottom of the page.

```
<?php
    function generate_options($from,$to,$callback=false)
{
    $reverse=false;

    if($from>$to)
    {
        $tmp=$from;
        $from=$to;
        $to=$tmp;

        $reverse=true;
    }
  ......
?>
```

Comment: Yes it is facebook-like-registration and I have all the related code to it.
Problem : It do not show any sort of error,but their is no values shown in drop down menu.

Comment: it wont show the error because it is inside the <select tag, if you view-source the page, you'll see the errors there.

Comment: :Thanks for reply. Here is link to zip file "http://www.sendspace.com/file/0hey8j". I can't find any error in page-source.If u wanna see.

Comment: I just tried it, and it works. http://i.imgur.com/CKNGb.png  What problem are you having anyway? is the dropdown showing on your end?

Comment: I have this function generate_option in different page "funtion.php"

Comment: SOLVED : Problem was short_open_tag .Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

generate_options is not internal PHP function.
For fix this code you should find definition of this function and insert it to your code

Comment: yes it is not internal Php function.Its user created function.Now the problem is same code is working on different system butnot on mine.
sendspace.com/file/0hey8j here it is, if you wanna check